# JSF selectOneMenu ajax doesn't fire listener

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf, listener, selectonemenu

The context is a form to add or modify an entry to/of a database table.
Inside of it, I want to create a search/selection subform with :

1. A search text input that request the database to fill a selectOneMenu
2. The dynamically filled selectOneMenu to select a value
3. A classic selectOneMenu with values hard-coded

So far I achieved to get the search text input to work only if I am modifying an existing entry (which id is passed via URL). It doesn't work if when I'm creating a new one.

The second problem is (in the case of modifying an entry, which is working already), when a value is chosen in the selectOneMenu, the listener seems to not be called. But with the selectOneMenu that have hard-coded values, it works fine. See **EDIT** for additional informations.

Here is the subform code :

```
<h:form>
    <h2>#{msg['addPeopleToFilm']}</h2>
    <div class="inputWrapper"> 
        <h:inputText id="search" value="#{beanPersonne.recherche}" >
            <f:ajax listener="#{beanPersonne.searchStringChanged}" render="output" event="change" />
        </h:inputText>
        <label>#{msg['personSearch']}</label>
    </div>

    <div class="selectWrapper" >
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{beanFilm.idToAdd}" id="output" >
            <f:selectItems 
            value = "#{beanPersonne.resultatsRechercheDynamique}" 
            var="personne" 
            itemValue="#{personne.idPersonne}"
            itemLabel="#{personne.prenom} #{personne.nom}" /> 
            <f:ajax listener="#{beanFilm.idToAddChanged}" render="idToAdd" event="change" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </div>

        <div class="selectWrapper" >
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{beanFilm.categoryChoice}" id="category"> 
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['actor']} ›" itemValue="0" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['producer']} ›" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['director']} ›" itemValue="2" />
            <f:ajax listener="#{beanFilm.categoryChoiceChanged}" render="categoryChoice" event="change" />
            </h:selectOneMenu> 
        </div>

    <h:commandButton value="Test">
    </h:commandButton>

    <h2><h:outputText id="idToAdd" value="#{beanFilm.idToAdd}" /></h2>
    <h2><h:outputText id="categoryChoice" value="#{beanFilm.categoryChoice}" /></h2>
</h:form>
```

And here is most of my bean beanFilm (almost the same in beanPersonne):

public class BeanFilm implements Serializable {

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 807253156212218187L;
    private Film film = new Film();
    private String recherche = new String();
    private String idToAdd = new String();
    private String categoryChoice = new String();
    private List<Film> resultatsRechercheDynamique = new ArrayList<Film>();


    public List<Film> getResultatsRechercheFilmPro() {
        return DAOFilmJPA.getInstance().getFilmsParTitre(recherche);
    }

    public String searchByTitle(String title)
    {
        recherche = title;
        this.resultatsRechercheDynamique = getResultatsRechercheFilmPro();
        return null;
    }

    public void searchStringChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe)
    {
        searchByTitle(recherche);
    }


    public void idToAddChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe)
    {
        // HERE GOES FUTURE CODE
    }

    public void categoryChoiceChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe)
    {
        // HERE GOES FUTURE CODE
    }


    public List<Film> getResultatsRechercheDynamique() {
        return resultatsRechercheDynamique;
    }

    public void setResultatsRechercheDynamique(
            List<Film> resultatsRechercheDynamique) {
        this.resultatsRechercheDynamique = resultatsRechercheDynamique;
    }

        public Film getFilm() {
        return film;
    }

    public void setFilm(Film film) {
        this.film = film;
    }

    public int getIdFilm() {
        return film.getIdFilm();
    }

    public void setIdFilm(int id) {
        film = DAOFilmJPA.getInstance().get(id);
    }

    public String getRecherche() {
        return recherche;
    }

    public void setRecherche(String recherche) {
        this.recherche = recherche;
    }

    public String doRecherche() {
        return "toResultatsRecherche";
    }

    public String getIdToAdd() {
        return idToAdd;
    }

    public void setIdToAdd(String idToAdd) {
        this.idToAdd = idToAdd;
    }

    public String getCategoryChoice() {
        return categoryChoice;
    }

    public void setCategoryChoice(String categoryChoice) {
        this.categoryChoice = categoryChoice;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If I add a selectItem with fixed value in the first selectOneMenu, next to the selectItem**s**, it triggers the listener just fine, but only on this entry, not those generated by selectItem**s**.
With debug mode, I found that selecting a value generated by selectItem**s** doesn't call the linked listener, while it is called when using selectItem.

Comment: Try `change` for the event name. Also look in your javascript console for clues

Comment: I just tried `change` event, and modified my code to use `f:ajax listener` instead of `valueChangedListener` but nothing changed so far. My javascript console doesn't provide any information. Please see my **EDIT** for additional details.

Comment: For starters, always add `<h:messages>` to the form (and ajax-update it), or at least take the effort to read the server logs and JS console if something appears to be failing silently in client side. You should have noticed a missing "Validation Error: Value is not valid" message.

Comment: Your comment and link for duplicate helped me a lot. By using `h:message` and changing my bean scope to `view` I achieved my goal. Thank you very much.